# how to rename/hide files names from user view/use on windows .bat batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, encryption, recursion, cmd

i'm willing to have a windows batch .bat script that hide files by renaming them and log the renaming into a file to undo it later.

---

privacy : sometime i don't want other people using my PC to see some of my files as they might be considered as personnal (yeah PC is for Personal Computer), i need to hide them from public view.
3 options:
-use a full featured encryption SW to encrypt the file & folder i want to hide -- 100% efficient but **way too slow and heavy** when processing lots of files...
-play with a zipper as 7z and compress/decompress with a password and 256bits AES -- efficient but **very long too and not easy in case of modifying** the file content...
-OR simply have the name of files fully renamed : no explicit name, a standard random computer generated name, so no one would guess what is inside and plainly think it's a system file. (And of course no extension!! .mp3 .avi .txt .xls etc...) This way file are still accessible if you know (i mean I KNOW) how to open them. On a windows OS that hold 130000+ files, who will find my secrets files? (hope no one will ;-) )

---

So i need a .bat script that rename all theses files into that and undo it.
The script might be able to go recursively through folder and rename folders as well...

expected behavior is like this :

```
hide_my_folders.bat folder_path
```

expected before/after is like this :

```
secret_folder1*                  --->              124-235-4443-4546*
secret_folder2*                  --->              5461-659-3-14*
my_secret_agenda.txt             --->              156-1658-3-44
my_secret_picture.jpg            --->              16971-2326-11-1
my_secret_recording.mp3          --->              1234-1445-788-99
```

*folders stays folders but all names are scrambled

---

To get started, i already have a .bat script that rename everything in the hard-coded folder d:\2sort\ (no recursion)

so i need some help to add :
-the recursion (hard coded or may be as an option on the command line   "/s"...)
-parameter input (pass the folder as parameter)

note the : SET TranslationFile=5173-19632-45713-132
as it is the file containing the original name list to reverse the renaming

```
@ECHO OFF

REM Randomly renames every file in a directory.

SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

REM HARD SETUP INTO d:\2sort\
d:
cd d:\2sort\

REM HARDCODED TRANSLATION FILE WITH EXPLICIT NAME VIOLATION AS 45713 > 2^15=32768 
SET TranslationFile=5173-19632-45713-132

IF NOT EXIST %TranslationFile% (
    ECHO Rename files mode  %CD%
    ECHO Type "OK" to continue.
    SET /P Confirm=
    IF /I NOT {!Confirm!}=={OK} (
        ECHO Aborting.
        GOTO :EOF
    )

    ECHO Original Name/Random Name > %TranslationFile%
    ECHO ------------------------- >> %TranslationFile%

    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('DIR /A:-D /B') DO (
        IF NOT %%A==%~nx0 (
            IF NOT %%A==%TranslationFile% (
                SET Use=%%~xA
                SET Use=.

                SET NewName=!RANDOM!-!RANDOM!-!RANDOM!-!RANDOM!!Use!
                ECHO %%A/!NewName!>> %TranslationFile%

                RENAME "%%A" "!NewName!"
            )
        )
    )
) ELSE (
    ECHO Undo rename mode  %CD%
    ECHO Type "OK" to continue.
    SET /P Confirm=
    IF /I NOT {!Confirm!}=={OK} (
        ECHO.
        ECHO Aborting.
        GOTO :EOF
    )

    FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%A IN (%TranslationFile%) DO RENAME "%%B" "%%A"
    DEL /F /Q %TranslationFile%
)
```

& thanks

Comment: I've made a script that protects your folders and files, do you want to try?

Comment: saudações @Rafael! any easy&working suitable solution is good enough for me... as long as it is in english (or french :-p  but english is better to share w the world!!)

Comment: There are applications built for this that are free you know. http://wisecleaner.com/wisefolderhider.html

Comment: thanks @Rich, i've heard of TrueCrypt instead, these SW are forbid me access to files while **hidden**, are wwway too complicated, and require too much user input/action... i just need an .bat file, click on it --> hidden, click on it --> undo

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/hndsofts/home/iprotect/iProtect%20v.2.0.rar

Unfortunately it's only in portuguese, but you just need to create an account and type the path to your file or folder.

Comment: dear @Rafael; your so called 'script' is indeed in portuguese; is 44KB long; using 2 external .exe progs coming from god knows where and was packed .rar with sality/win32 virus. I'll pass on it...

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off 
setlocal

SET root_dir=%~1
SET root_dir=d:\2test

REM -------------------------------------------------------
REM -- PUSHD all directories tree --
SET /A COUNT=1
FOR /D /R %root_dir%  %%G in (*) DO (
    Pushd "%%G"
    SET /A COUNT+=1
)


REM -------------------------------------------------------
REM -- POPD all directories to process them in reverse order ( \d1\d1.1 must be processed before \d1) --
:while
IF %COUNT% gtr 1 (

  REM -- PROCESS CURRENT FOLDER --
  CALL :process_folder

  popd
  SET /A COUNT-=1
  GOTO :while
)

REM -- PROCESS ROOT FOLDER --
CD %root_dir%
CALL :process_folder

REM -------------------------------------------------------
REM -- ALL DONE --> now exit --
GOTO :EOF


REM -------------------------------------------------------
REM PROCESS THE DIRECTORY
:process_folder

pwd

SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

REM HARDCODED TRANSLATION FILE WITH EXPLICIT NAME VIOLATION AS 45713 > 2^15=32768 
SET TranslationFile=5173-19632-45713-132

IF NOT EXIST %TranslationFile% (
    ECHO Original Name/Random Name > %TranslationFile%
    ECHO ------------------------- >> %TranslationFile%

    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('DIR /A /B') DO (
        IF NOT %%A==%~nx0 (
            IF NOT %%A==%TranslationFile% (
                SET Use=%%~xA
                SET Use=.

                SET NewName=!RANDOM!-!RANDOM!-!RANDOM!-!RANDOM!!Use!
                ECHO %%A/!NewName!>> %TranslationFile%

                RENAME "%%A" "!NewName!"
            )
        )
    )
) ELSE (
    FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%A IN (%TranslationFile%) DO RENAME "%%B" "%%A"
    DEL /F /Q %TranslationFile%
)


:EOF
```

output is run twice (do/undo)

```
D:\>test
d:\2test\d2\d2.1
d:\2test\d1\d1.1\d1.1.2
d:\2test\d1\d1.1\d1.1.1
d:\2test\d1\d1.1
d:\2test\d2
d:\2test\d1
Access is denied.
d:\2test
Access is denied.
Access is denied.

D:\>test
d:\2test\d2\16516-17860-21197-21380
d:\2test\d1\d1.1\9568-2224-16391-19037
d:\2test\d1\d1.1\23997-552-22581-12114
d:\2test\d1\d1.1
d:\2test\d2
d:\2test\d1
The system cannot find the file specified.
d:\2test
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.

D:\>
```

almost good, i have an unfortunate and nasty access denied from windows... so some folders cannot be renamed!
anyone to help fix it?
note: hardcoded in "d:\2test\" for testing

thanks